# $A = \left\{ (x,y):\min \left\{ (x - 1)^2 - y^2,(x + 1)^2 - y^2,x^2 - (y - 1)^2,x^2 - (y + 1)^2 \right\} \le 1 \right\}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $$A = \left\{ (x,y):\min \left\{ (x - 1)^2 - y^2,(x + 1)^2 - y^2,x^2 - (y - 1)^2,x^2 - (y + 1)^2 \right\} \le 1 \right\}$$

Can we say that,  $A$ is  the union of
four closed discs with centres at  $1, -1, i,-i$?

Comment: No. $(x-1)^2-y^2\leq 1$ is not a disk around anything, it is the interior of a hyperbola.

Comment: Your MathJax code looked like something written by a lunatic.  I cleaned it up. $\qquad$

Comment: Interesting thought, but no. $x, y \in \mathbb R$; this is not over complex numbers. If it were, it would be in two dimensions over $\mathbb C$, so you wouldn't be talking about "disks" anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Have a little respect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got four hyperbolas.  The region described by the set you specified looks like this:

[image]

The individual regions are shown in this more detailed plot:

[image]

Now, if you had instead written:  $$B = \left\{(x,y) : \min\left((x - 1)^2 + y^2, (x + 1)^2 + y^2, x^2 + (y - 1)^2, x^2 + (y + 1)^2\right) \le 1 \right\},$$ we would indeed have the union of the four discs as shown below:

[image]

To understand why the minimum corresponds to the union of regions defined by the constituent inequalities, consider sets defined by $$S_i = \{(x,y) : f_i(x,y) \le r\}, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$$ for some functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and a **shared** constant $r \in \mathbb R$.  Now define the set $$S_\cup = \{(x,y) : (\min_i f_i(x,y)) \le r\}.$$  We reason that $S_\cup = \bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$ as follows.  If $(x,y) \in S_\cup,$ then clearly there exists an $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $f_i(x,y) \le r$, consequently $(x,y) \in S_i$, hence $S_\cup \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$.  Conversely, choose any $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and suppose $(x,y) \in S_j$.  Then $f_j(x,y) \le r$.  if $(x,y) \not \in S_\cup$, this would imply $\min_i f_i(x,y) > r$, or equivalently, $f_i(x,y) > r$ for **every** $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, which contradicts the fact that $f_j(x,y) \le r$.  Consequently $(x,y) \in S_j$ implies $(x,y) \in S_\cup$, and since this is true for **each** $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, it follows that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i \subseteq S_\cup$, and the claim is proven.

Comment: Without drawing shapes, how can we prove?